# Problems with macports and gnuplot different users

Tags: macos, terminal, gnuplot, macports

I installed MacPorts (in an Administrator account, Mac OS X 10.8.2), and then `gnuplot` through it. But in another account (without admin privileges), I can't launch `gnuplot` nor `port` from the terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ gnuplot
-bash: gnuplot: command not found
MacBook-Pro:~ user$ port
-bash: port: command not found
```

What is going on. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `/opt/local/bin` to your `$PATH`.

This is done by adding this to your `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

This is done when you install MacPorts, but I guess not to all users (you installed it as a different user).

I don't know why it doesn't update `/etc/profile` and make it global, but I would recommend you do that manually if you have multiple users of that system.

Comment: @Manuel Check for `~/.bash_profile`, but if that doesn't exist then just create it with the lines above.

Comment: @trojanfoe There's a recent discussion on one of the MacPorts lists about why the project does not automatically setup `/etc/paths.d` (which is what is used by `/etc/profile` and `path_helper`): the extra paths are appended to the default `PATH`.  Starts about here: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/31213

Comment: @NedDeily This is why you could use `/etc/profile` to update `$PATH` and `$MANPATH` globally by modifying it at **after** `path_helper` has run.

Comment: @trojanfoe Except that `/etc/profile` is an Apple-controlled file; it is subject to being overwritten at any time by OS X updates.

Comment: @NedDeily Yeah, that would be an issue.

Comment: @NedDeily Then this solution works or will be broken every OS X update?

Comment: @Manuel, no, changing your profile is fine. That's a file under your control.