# Undo changes with Mac Terminal (while attempting to share OpenCV with different users)

Tags: python, macos, bash, terminal, macports

I've installed opencv and python binding with macport. I can import it in python with an user but not with the other.

```
iMac-di-Casa:~ giacomo$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
>>> exit()
```

I try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047381/problems-with-macports-and-gnuplot-different-users) but I've done two mistakes: `path` instead `PATH` and `sahre`instead of  `share`. This is what I've typed in terminal:

```
iMac-di-Casa:~ giacomo$ export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$path
iMac-di-Casa:~ giacomo$ export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
iMac-di-Casa:~ giacomo$ export MANPATH=/opt/local/sahre/man:$MANPATH
iMac-di-Casa:~ giacomo$ export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

Now nothing works:

```
iMac-di-Casa:~ giacomo$ python
-bash: python: command not found
```

How can I repair my mistakes? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seriously, just log out and in again.

Comment: Try this: `exec /bin/bash -l`